Angular Signals and Component Structure
I have watched various Angular 18 courses such as those by Deborah Kurata and it seems that the recommended pattern is as follows.
UI Component <-- Signals <-- Observable <-- Web Api <-- Database etc.
Only the service contains Observables and the UI makes use of Signals in the service that wrap the observables.
I am trying to understand how this works in my example.  I have a search UI component, list UI component and a service.  The search UI component contains the various search fields to find a customer.  The list component shows a list of customers.  The service component invokes a web api to get the customers based on the search components.
Can't work out the correct calling sequence.  Should the list component iterate through the list signal of the service. The service would need to know the search parameters to do this.
Does the service contain class variables to allow the search params to be set by the search ui component?  This would not trigger the observable to run so do I make the search params also signals ?
The service is working as expected. I do have a side issue in that for some reason the list will not iterate through the signal wrapped observable but will iterate via the observable if I subscribe to it.

are you using the respective signal in the template?

My plan is to have the create a signal in the service for each of the search parameters.  Then create a computed signal that wraps the observable.  The theory being that the observable goes to get the data each time a search param is changed.  The UI list component uses the computed signal from the service.  The search UI component changes the search parameter signals.

it should work, but you need to use a signal in the template to make a binding for change detection
